# How to use create method with variables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, variables, methods, model, oncreate

How can i define create method with variables and model in laravel? Like this:

```
public function createMethodName($variable, $variable2)
{
   \App\ModelName::create([...]);
}
```

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: What is the create method upper function? That is the exact question.

Comment: Dont you read laravel documents on how to create models?

Answer (score 0):

You have to just insert the passed variables in the `array` like:

```
// include model at the top of your file:
use \App\Models\ModelName;

public function createMethodName($variable1, $variable2)
{
    $my_stuff = ModelName::create([
       ‘something’ => $variable1,
       ‘something_else’ => $variable2,
    ]);
}
```

Also, do not forget to make some of your Model fields `fillable` (fields which are included in the array) in your Model, if you want to save values to the table with using `create()`. Check the  Reference about this:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

**Short update:**

Maybe I misunderstood your question a bit since according to your new comments under your question it is getting clearer that you maybe first would like to create a **Table** with `Schema::create()` method (which is a totally different part of the fun). Reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-tables

Then after you created your **Table**, you can create a **Model** using artisan like:
`php artisan make:model ModelName`
Reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#defining-models

and then you can use `ModelName::create()` method in your **Controller** as I gave it above to saving your **data** into your Table. So you should study these steps a bit more if it is the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zollie. I will try this solution.

Comment: Hi @BektaşÇimen, I updated my answer to make things clearer. :)

Comment: Good morning, @BektaşÇimen - if you would like to, you can edit your question and put more details in your question about what you want to achieve and that way we can probably help you more.